# How to fix lint false positive checks on AGP 7.1.1 + Kotlin 1.7.10?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I have updated kotlin version from 1.6.10 to 1.7.10 and got a log of false positive results from lint checks.

I have checked few results and they are false positive.

With kotlin 1.6.10 the lint works perfect

Gradle Version 7.4
AGP 7.1.1
Kotlin 1.7.10